# Laravel external URL issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I want to set external URL in some of my anchor tags but facing problem when URL is without http/https protocol. When URL is without these protocols URL become like following:

```
<a target="_blank" href="www.usatoday.com/"></a>
```

when I click on it or hover over it, it shows and redirect me to:
    http://localhost/event/www.usatoday.com

I've tried following two ways in href but didn't worked:

```
{{url($eventSponsorsRow->sponsorUrl)}}
{{ $eventSponsorsRow->sponsorUrl }}
```

instead of URL in href. Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 16):

This is HTML and browser stuff, not Laravel/PHP itself.

You just need to provide protocol part of the url to make it external.

You can skip the `http:` but it needs at least double slash in front of the url like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="//www.usatoday.com/"></a>
```

Please not, that if you skip the `http(s):` part it will use currently used protocol.

Comment: it worked like you sad, but if I write these '//' hard coded then it'll will stop working if user enter URL with those protocol. Is there a way to handle it or I have to handle it myself like in PHP?

Comment: Of course hardcoding `//` is a bad idea. You should validate and filter the url value when it comes form the user. At that point you should add/remove http part depending on how you would like to store urls in your DB.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prepend http:// to the url

if you want to use *{{url($eventSponsorsRow->sponsorUrl)}}* make sure when you insert into a database it prepends http:// with it

`<a target="_blank" href="{{ url($eventSponsorsRow->sponsorUrl) }}"></a>`

if you don't want to do that you will need to create a variable with the url you are getting from the database and prepend the http://

`$newvariable = "http://$eventSponsorsRow->sponsorUrl";`
and call the $newvariable in the correct location

`<a target="_blank" href="{{ $newvariable }}"></a>`

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-blade-external-url-link-reading-url-from-database

Comment: You don't need `http://` or `https://`. Just prefix the URL with `//` and that will use the same scheme as the page it is on.