# How to show images with absolute path avoiding laravel to add base url?

Tags: laravel-blade, absolute-path

I was showing images in laravel blade with absolute path I get from the database, it is working fine. 
I am talking about external images. The images urls are "https://somedomain.name/attachments/blablabla.png".
But now laravel adds the base url and my images are not found. 
Laravel provides now : "https://localhost/https://somedomain.name/attachments/blablabla.png"
Even if I added , it added the current url as prefix to images urls. How to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel then its Bad practice to Store Direct URL to your Database.

1. You should make your own folder (for Eg. images) in Laravel Public Folder where you have to add images.
2. In upload Image code use move($imageName, $path) you should add Images to this folder and only Image name store in your Database. You should also customize your Image Name at the time of upload Image.
3. For getting your Image path to display at Blade you can use Image Name only at url link url('/images/'.$myImage); & at Blade you'll get result like that

   `<img src={{url('/images/photo.type')}} width="" height="" alt=""/>`

Comment: I am talking about external images. not images I download in my app. The images url are "https://somedomain.name/attachments/blablabla.png.

Comment: can you share code for understanding and Error that you are getting

Comment: I have already updated by post. the browser console says the images are not found because the links are not correct. It seems it is same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142229/laravel-external-url-issue?rq=1 and none of the propositions work

Comment: I am not using url function. I never said that. did you read my post? You are confused. it is <img src="{{ $myImg }}"> right?

Comment: Thanks this `{{ url('/images/photo.type') }}` works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause and the solutionsince few days. But it is now I have some minutes to put the answer.
I have this issue because my urls get from csv file are surrounded by quotes. So I removed all quotes with SQL query for this field and I reload my page and everything is perfect.
Here is my sql query: (for postgresql)

```
update public.mytable set img_url= REPLACE(img_url,'"','')
```

If you have this issue but you do not want to remove quotes with SQL, you cannot remove quotes with the programming language you are using (here PHP) before put the variable as url source tag like this :

```
<img src={{url($the_var_trimmed_by_quote)}} alt=""/>
```

Maybe this would help you: [Remove quotes from start and end of string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734758/remove-quotes-from-start-and-end-of-string-in-php). But it does not work for me,because quotes formats look like different. You can also search how to do it by another way. But now you know what can create this issue, so find solution will be more easier.
Thank you all